# $\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}f(x) dx \geq C$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:[\epsilon, 2\epsilon] \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$ continuous. Is it possible to show that
> $$
> \int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}f(x) dx \geq C ?
> $$
> where $C$ is a positive constant that does not depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Think: you're trying to make a rectangle with ever-decreasing width to have at least a constant area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous.

One interpretation is

> Can we show that for all functions $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^+$ there is a constant $C$ such
> that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon} f(x)\textrm{ d}x > C$?

The answer to this question is "No".

If $f(x) = 1$ then $f$ is continuous and positive on $[0,1]$, and $\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon} 1 \textrm{ d} x  = \epsilon $.  Clearly $\epsilon$ cannot be bounded from below by a positive constant $C$ independent of $\epsilon$.

However, your question could also be interpreted to be asking:

> Can we find an example of a function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^+$ and a constant $C$ such
> that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon} f(x)\textrm{ d}x > C$?

The answer to this question was answered in the affirmative by @user619894.  Their example is

$C={1\over 2}$, $f(x)={1\over x}$, $$\begin{align*}
\int _{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} {1\over x} dx &= \log(2\epsilon) - \log(\epsilon)\\ &= \log(\frac{2\epsilon}{\epsilon}) \\&= \log(2)\\ &=0.69... \\&> {1\over 2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You're right! Thank you!

Comment: unless f is unbounded, e.g. $1\over x$

Comment: @user253963, yes, but not independent of $a,b$

Comment: @user619894 I don't understand

Comment: @user253963 The maximum in $[a,b]$ could be dependent on $a$

Comment: Nowhere was it stated that $f$ is defined on zero, only that it was defined on intervals $[\epsilon, 2\epsilon]$ for positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: @user619894 The original poster left out quantifiers, which makes the question ambiguous.  My interpretation of the question was "Can we show that for all functions $f$ there is a constant $C$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$ we have $\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon} f(x) \textrm{ dx} > C$?".  My answer shows that the answer to this questions is trivially "No".  Your interpretation seems to be "Can we find a function $f$ so that there exists $C$ so that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon} f(x) \textrm{ dx} > C$?".  Your solution to that different question is also valid!

Comment: @StevenGubkin actually OP wrote " let $f:[\epsilon, 2\epsilon] \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$ continuous", YMMV

Comment: @user619894 Do you agree that, as written, the question is ambiguous?

Comment: @StevenGubkin not to me, but I guess both answers are out there now. Let OP decide what they _meant_ to ask.

Comment: @StevenGubkin  On second thought how about you add the other option to your answer (e.g. " if the conditions only demand continuity on the open interval $(0,1]$ there is a counter example ..."). Then I will delete my answer, and upvote yours. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, I will make it CW to be fair about points, and attribution.

Comment: @user619894 done!

Comment: So, first interpretation?

Comment: @user253963 Your question was not clear.  You cannot have two valid contradictory answers to the same question.  So if you are saying both answers are valid, then you must be admitting that the question was ambiguous.